# SVHN Data questions

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, hdf5, h5py

I have been reading and working on SO questions related to the Street View House Numbers (SVHN) datasets. The files are available at 2 different locations:

**Stanford:**
[The Street View House Numbers (SVHN) Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers)

**kaggle:**
[Street View House Numbers (SVHN) | Kaggle](http://kaggle.com/stanfordu/street-view-house-numbers)

My question is related to the format of the `digitStruct.mat` files for each image set (train, test, and extras). These define the name, label, and bounding box dimensions for each image. As I understand, the mat file is written as a Matlab structure in HDF5 format (that can be read with `h5py`).

I have been able to access and read the `digitStruct.mat` files from kaggle with `h5py`. I cannot open the same files from the Stanford site with `h5py` (or with HDFView). Some SO posts I've read indicate the Stanford files are an older Matlab format and should be read with `scipy.io.loadmat`.

- Are the files at Stanford and kaggle the same?
- If not, what are the differences?
- Should I be able to open the Stanford `digitStruct.mat` files with `h5py`?
- If so, what method should I use to download and extract the Standford tar.gz files? (FYI, I'm on Win-7, and have been using HTTP download and WinZip to extract.)

I am adding additional info to document different behavior observed with different .mat files. It may help with diagnosis.

I can open and operate on .mat files from kaggle with this call:

```
h5f = h5py.File('digitStruct.mat','r')
```

For files from Stanford, I get different errors depending on the file and function used to open.

The command below executes without an error message. That leads me to believe it is not a Matlab v7.3 file that can be opened with h5py.

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('./Stanford/test_32x32.mat')
```

Both of these calls do not work (brief error message provided):

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('./test/digitStruct.mat')
Traceback...
NotImplementedError: Please use HDF reader for matlab v7.3 files

h5f = h5py.File('./test/digitStruct.mat','r')
Traceback...
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

In addition, I cannot open `test/digitStruct.mat` with HDFView. My conclusion for the Stanford digitStruct.mat files: they might be Matlab v7.3 files, but were corrupted when I downloaded. However, I'm not sure what I did wrong (since I can download and read kaggle files without problems).

Answer (score 2):

With some Linux detective work, I figured out the problem.
As I suspected, the `digitStruct.mat` files extracted from the `*.tar.gz` files on the Stanford site are HDF5 (Matlab v7.3) files, and were corrupted when I downloaded.

To confirm, I downloaded the 3 tar.gz files with a browser on a Linux system, then used the `tar` command to extract them, and successfully opened with `h5py` on Linux. I then transferred them to my Windows system, and each worked as expected with `h5py`.

This is a little surprising, as I have used WinZip to extract tarball files in the past. Apparently there's something special about these that caused the corruption.
Hopefully this saves someone the same headache in the future.

Note: the 3 `xxxx_32x32.mat` files are an older Matlab format that must be accessed with `scipy.io.loadmat()`